# How to interpret/choose alpha in ridge regression

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, overfitting, ridge-regression, feature-engineering

I have questions on how to apply ridge regression on my data set, which has about 75 samples with 8 features (x's) and usually 3 targets (y's).

I tried the following feature engineering methods.

1. only use the first order features ($x_i$);
2. first order + 2nd order w/o interaction terms ($x_i, x_i^2$);
3. first order + all 2nd terms ($x_i, x_i^2, x_ix_j$)

For each case, I always scale the X and Y values (even though it may not help) by:

```
x_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_all_scale = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_all)
Y_all_scale = y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_all)
```

and try to find the good **α** by **minimizing the validation set MSE in 10-fold cv.**

```
alpha = np.logspace(-5, 1, 7, endpoint=True)
```

Here is what I got for the three cases and I don't know whether I understand right.

Case 1: $X={x_i}$. mean_MSE = 0.40 ~ 0.45, fitting $R^2$=0.83 ~ 0.84. Value may vary in 10-fold cv. Best alpha is either 0.01 to 0.0001.

Case 2: $X={x_i, x_i^2}$. mean_MSE = 0.38 ~ 0.39, fitting $R^2$=0.88 ~ 0.89. Value may vary in 10-fold cv. Best alpha is either 0.01 or 0.001.

Case 3: $X={x_i, x_i^2, x_ix_j}$. mean_MSE = 0.35 ~ 0.39, fitting $R^2$=0.91 ~ 0.96. Value may vary in 10-fold cv. Best alpha is either 1 or 10.

Based on the MSE and $R^2$, it looks like Case 3 is the best choice. However, the **alpha value is always very big** -- it may indicate that the model is **high-bias (under-fit due to too high dimension w/ relatively small data): it's very bad and only learnt the mean.**

**My question is how can I know whether case 3 is a high-bias model and which case is should I choose.**

Thank you all!

Comment: Could you please clarify what "alpha" is?  Presumably it weights the penalty term, but how exactly?  And what do you mean by "$R^2$"? I doubt it's the intrinsic $R^2,$ because that's an invalid way to compare models--so perhaps it's the $R^2$ of the test data?  But then one wouldn't expect it to improve with the grossly overfit model in case 3.

Comment: @whuber, 1. Yes, 'alpha' is the penalty coefficient of the penalty term in ridge regression. 2. $R^2$ is the $R^2$ score when I fit the data on the whole dataset after find the best alpha in 10-fold cv [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score). What do you mean by saying "intrinsic $R^2$"?

Comment: @whuber, Since case 3 has very big alpha value, my concern is it is underfit, rather than overfit. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't explained how alpha works to penalize the objective.  It sounds like it multiplies the penalty term.  By "intrinsic" I mean based on the training data only.

Comment: @whuber, Yes, it multiplies the penalty terms and this is the definition of ridge regression, right? I use sklearn ridge regression implementation and you can find the link [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)

Comment: People parameterize the penalty terms in different ways: there is not a unique way to do it.  That's why you need to tell us which way you're using.

Comment: @whuber. I don't understand what you mean by "parameterize the penalty terms in different ways". As my understanding, ridge regression = linear regression + l2 regularization . l2 regularization is the only way in ridge regression. Probably we are talking about different things. Can you give an example of a way that people parameterize the penalty term?

Comment: The $L^2$ penalty is proportional to the sum of squares of the coefficients.  Is the constant of proportionality equal to $\alpha$ or to $1/\alpha$ or to $\exp(\alpha)$ or something else?

Comment: @whuber. the constant of proportionality equal to $α$